# How much secure data stored in sessionstorage and localstorage in Browsers

Tags: html, session, caching, storage

I am a newbie in web application development.Recently i got  a chance to use 
SessionStorage and LocalStorage . I have seen most browsers saving the data in browser cache in sqlite or as web storge either in Base64 or in plain text format.
How much secure this or we need to implemnent some encryption before saving into the storage?

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of web storage, which differ in scope and lifetime:

Local storage (window.localStorage) — The local storage uses the localStorage object to store data for your entire website, permanently. That means the stored local data will be available on the next day, the next week, or the next year unless you remove it.

Session storage (window.sessionStorage) — The session storage uses the sessionStorage object to store data on a temporary basis, for a single window (or tab). The data disappears when session ends i.e. when the user closes that window (or tab).

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Also check this thread
 [Does HTML5 web storage (localStorage) offer a security advantage over cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687705/does-html5-web-storage-localstorage-offer-a-security-advantage-over-cookies)